# Applying Group policy - "The Specified server Cannot perform the requested operation"

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Setting up a new domain for a SME, Win server 2012R2. I've set the server up, configured AD DNS etc, Applied a couple of group policies to test that AD is working, and none of the test machines (Win 7 and 8.1, both clean installs) can get either computer or user policies.
The computers can all see the server via DNS and IP connections, I can log in to any of the test (Administrator and user) accounts, and I can browse shares on the server.

Running Gpupdate /force directs me to look at the event log and I'm getting an Event ID 1030 from Group Policy with an Error Code of 58

> The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

I've got a funny feeling I've missed something obvious here, but my Google-Fu appears to be failing me.